# Condition gets false even if matching seems true in beanshell jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting URL based on previous **POST** request and checking for specific string in URL.

URL is : `https://www.example.com/index/checkout`

**Code to check specific text in URL**

```
String URL = prev.getURL().toString();
vars.put("URL", URL);

      if("${URL}".contains("index"))
      {
           log.info("PASS");
      }
     else
      {
        log.info("FAIL");

      }
```

My URL already contains "index" but above conditions always get **FALSE**.

I tried by checking `log.info(URL)` and it returns me exact URL with word "index".

I am using **BeanShell PostProcessor** for above in jmeter.

Comment: Can you try below code?

String URL = "https://www.example.com/index/checkout";


vars.put("URL", URL);

      if(!"${URL}".equals("index"))
      {
           log.info("PASS");
      }
     else
      {
        log.info("FAIL");

      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't inline JMeter Variables and/or Functions into Beanshell script**.

You should be using [`vars.get("URL");`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get(java.lang.String)) instead of `"${URL}"` as `"${URL}"` string doesn't contain `index`. You can double check it by adding `log.info("${URL}");` line to your script.

```
String URL = "https://www.example.com/index/checkout";

vars.put("URL", URL);

if (vars.get("URL").contains("index")) {
    log.info("PASS");
} else {
    log.info("FAIL");
}
```

[image: JMeter Beanshell Demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive explanation and other tips.